# get the value of DisplayName attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

```
public class Class1
{
    [DisplayName("Something To Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How to get the value of DisplayName attribute in C# ?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try these utility methods of mine:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;


public static T GetAttribute<T>(this MemberInfo member, bool isRequired)
    where T : Attribute
{
    var attribute = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).SingleOrDefault();

    if (attribute == null && isRequired)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            string.Format(
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                "The {0} attribute must be defined on member {1}", 
                typeof(T).Name, 
                member.Name));
    }

    return (T)attribute;
}

public static string GetPropertyDisplayName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
{
    var memberInfo = GetPropertyInformation(propertyExpression.Body);
    if (memberInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "No property reference expression was found.",
            "propertyExpression");
    }

    var attr = memberInfo.GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(false);
    if (attr == null)
    {
        return memberInfo.Name;
    }

    return attr.DisplayName;
}

public static MemberInfo GetPropertyInformation(Expression propertyExpression)
{
    Debug.Assert(propertyExpression != null, "propertyExpression != null");
    MemberExpression memberExpr = propertyExpression as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpr == null)
    {
        UnaryExpression unaryExpr = propertyExpression as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpr != null && unaryExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
        {
            memberExpr = unaryExpr.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
    }

    if (memberExpr != null && memberExpr.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        return memberExpr.Member;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Usage would be:

```
string displayName = ReflectionExtensions.GetPropertyDisplayName<SomeClass>(i => i.SomeProperty);
```

Comment: Could u help me to find out proper way to iterate through all properties DisplayName, please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12868901/how-to-iterate-through-the-all-model-properties-mvc-4

Comment: @rich-tebb It seems this doesn't work when you have  [Display(Name = "SomeProperty", ResourceType = typeof(SomeResource))], it doesn't return localized name. Will try to modify it so it does.

Comment: Added a little code snippet how to read the localized value from DisplayAttribute.

Comment: public static T GetAttribute<T>(this extension method cannot be declared in a non-generic, non-nested static class

Comment: public static ThankYou

Answer (score 45):

First off, you need to get a `MemberInfo` object that represents that property. You will need to do some form of reflection:

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(Class1).GetProperty("Name");
```

(I'm using "old-style" reflection, but you can also use an expression tree if you have access to the type at compile-time)

Then you can fetch the attribute and obtain the value of the `DisplayName` property:

```
var attribute = property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true)
      .Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single();
string displayName = attribute.DisplayName;
```

() parentheses are required typo error

Comment: If the displayNameAttribute is null, this will fail. Instead of returning single try to return FirstOrDefault() then check whether this value is null or not.

Answer (score 34):

You need to get the `PropertyInfo` associated with the property (e.g. via `typeof(Class1).GetProperty("Name")`) and then call [`GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx).

It's a bit messy due to returning multiple values - you may well want to write a helper method to do this if you need it from a few places. (There may already be a helper method in the framework somewhere, but if there is I'm unaware of it.)

EDIT: As leppie pointed out, there *is* such a method: [`Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo, Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130863)

Comment: We got `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(MemberInfo, Type)`  :)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130863

Comment: @leppie: Ooh, nice. Not sure why I'd never spotted that.

Answer (score 14):

If anyone is interested in getting the localized string from the property with **DisplayAttribute** and **ResourceType** like this:

```cs
[Display(Name = "Year", ResourceType = typeof(ArrivalsResource))]
public int Year { get; set; }
```

Use the following after `displayAttribute != null` (as shown above by [@alex' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048758/3941350)):

```cs
ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(displayAttribute.ResourceType);
var entry = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true)
                           .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                           .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.ToString() == displayAttribute.Name);

return entry.Value.ToString();
```

Comment: `DisplayAttribute` has `GetName` method. No need for your code in .NET 4+ : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Salar While you are correct you're slightly misled - when a ResourceType is specified, then the `GetName()` method just returns the Key, and not the Value specified in the resources file.

Comment: @MattGriffiths what is this variable '**displayAttribute**' ?

Comment: @Dark_Knight that's probably the variable holding the result of that display attribute query, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10048758/3941350 for an example on how to do that.

Comment: as pointed out by Salar, it's better to use `.GetName()` instead of the code above, see the problem I had with the code above here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827360/with-entityframework-how-to-access-displayname-for-foreign-key-columns

Comment: Hi Matija , I'm looking for some help here in my question, I think maybe you could have some knowledge related. Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute

Answer (score 13):

```
var propInfo = typeof(Class1).GetProperty("Name");
var displayNameAttribute = propInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false);
var displayName = (displayNameAttribute[0] as DisplayNameAttribute).DisplayName;
```

`displayName` variable now holds the property's value.

Comment: That looks so hacky

Comment: I already had the propertyinfo and this is just what I needed. :-) And I did the missing null check with firstanddefault and "is".

Answer (score 12):

From within a view that has Class1 as it's strongly typed view model:

```
ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<Class1, string>(x => x.Name, ViewData).DisplayName;
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer... I assume it's smart enough to use the cached metadata objects internally; either way, nice and concise and using .net's own methods

Comment: Only available via System.Web.Mvc - not everybody does web apps, even in 2020..

Answer (score 10):

Nice classes by Rich Tebb!
I've been using DisplayAttribute and the code did not work for me. The only thing I've added is handling of DisplayAttribute. Brief search yielded that this attribute is new to MVC3 & .Net 4 and does almost the same thing plus more. Here's a modified version of the method:

```
 public static string GetPropertyDisplayString<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
    {
        var memberInfo = GetPropertyInformation(propertyExpression.Body);
        if (memberInfo == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                "No property reference expression was found.",
                "propertyExpression");
        }

        var displayAttribute = memberInfo.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false);

        if (displayAttribute != null)
        {
            return displayAttribute.Name;
        }
        else
        {
            var displayNameAttribute = memberInfo.GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(false);
            if (displayNameAttribute != null)
            {
                return displayNameAttribute.DisplayName;
            }
            else
            {
                return memberInfo.Name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I have this generic utility method. I pass in a list of a given type (Assuming you have a supporting class) and it generates a datatable with the properties as column headers and the list items as data.

Just like in standard MVC, if you dont have DisplayName attribute defined, it will fall back to the property name so you only have to include DisplayName where it is different to the property name.

```
    public DataTable BuildDataTable<T>(IList<T> data)
    {
        //Get properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        //.Where(p => !p.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual && !p.GetGetMethod().IsFinal).ToArray(); //Hides virtual properties

        //Get column headers
        bool isDisplayNameAttributeDefined = false;
        string[] headers = new string[Props.Length];
        int colCount = 0;
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            isDisplayNameAttributeDefined = Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));

            if (isDisplayNameAttributeDefined)
            {
                DisplayNameAttribute dna = (DisplayNameAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(prop, typeof(DisplayNameAttribute));
                if (dna != null)
                    headers[colCount] = dna.DisplayName;
            }
            else
                headers[colCount] = prop.Name;

            colCount++;
            isDisplayNameAttributeDefined = false;
        }

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        //Add column headers to datatable
        foreach (var header in headers)
            dataTable.Columns.Add(header);

        dataTable.Rows.Add(headers);

        //Add datalist to datatable
        foreach (T item in data)
        {
            object[] values = new object[Props.Length];
            for (int col = 0; col < Props.Length; col++)
                values[col] = Props[col].GetValue(item, null);

            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

If there's a more efficient / safer way of doing this, I'd appreicate any feedback. The commented //Where clause will filter out virtual properties. Useful if you are using model classes directly as EF puts in "Navigation" properties as virtual. However it will also filter out any of your own virtual properties if you choose to extend such classes. For this reason, I prefer to make a ViewModel and decorate it with only the needed properties and display name attributes as required, then make a list of them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(foo);

foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
{
    if (property.Name == "Name")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.DisplayName); // Something To Name
    }
}
```

where `foo` is an instance of `Class1`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `property` as `PropertyInfo` type, you can do this in one single line:

```
property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single().DisplayName
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party I know.

I use this:

```
public static string GetPropertyDisplayName(PropertyInfo pi)
{
  var dp = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
  return dp != null ? dp.DisplayName : pi.Name;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
EnumEntity.item.GetType().GetFields()[(int)EnumEntity.item].CustomAttributes.ToArray()[0].NamedArguments[0].TypedValue.ToString()
```

It will give you the value of data attribute `Name`.

Answer (score 1):

This works, thanks to someone above:

```cs
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties)
{
    var propName = pi.Name;
    var dp = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
    if (dp != null)
    {
        propName = dp.DisplayName; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're here for [Display(Name="")] below code might help:

```
var props = yourObject.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var item in props)
{
   string title = item.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayAttribute>().SingleOrDefault()?.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
String displayName = null;
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in properties){
     var displayAttribute = pi.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute));
    if (displayAttribute != null)
                {
                    displayName = (displayAttribute as DisplayAttribute).GetName();
                }
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Following Rich Tebb's and Matt Baker's answer, I wanted to use the `ReflectionExtensions` methods in a LINQ query, but it didn't work, so I've made this method for it to work.

If `DisplayNameAttribute` is set the method will return it, otherwise it will return the `MemberInfo` name.

Test method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lst = new List<Test>();
    lst.Add(new Test("coucou1", "kiki1"));
    lst.Add(new Test("coucou2", "kiki2"));
    lst.Add(new Test("coucou3", "kiki3"));
    lst.Add(new Test("coucou4", "kiki4"));
    lst.ForEach(i => 
        Console.WriteLine(i.GetAttributeName<Test>(t => t.Name) + ";" + i.GetAttributeName<Test>(t=>t.t2)));
}
```

Test method output:

[image: Test method output]

The class with `DisplayName1` Attribute:

```
public class Test
{
    public Test() { }
    public Test(string name, string T2)
    {
        Name = name;
        t2 = T2;
    }
    [DisplayName("toto")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string t2 { get; set; }
}
```

And the extension method:

```
public static string GetAttributeName<T>(this T itm, Expression<Func<T, object>> propertyExpression)
{
    var memberInfo = GetPropertyInformation(propertyExpression.Body);
    if (memberInfo == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "No property reference expression was found.",
            "propertyExpression");
    }

    var pi = typeof(T).GetProperty(memberInfo.Name);
    var ret = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
    return ret != null ? ret.DisplayName : pi.Name;
```

}

Comment: `GetPropertyInformation()` does not exist in this context. I've just realised that this code is present in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015911/6236042) below

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code, I think this will solve your problem.

```
var classObj = new Class1();
classObj.Name => "StackOverflow";

var property = new Class1().GetType().GetProperty(nameof(classObj.Name));
var displayNameAttributeValue = (property ?? throw new InvalidOperationException())
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute)) as DisplayNameAttribute; 

if (displayNameAttributeValue != null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", displayNameAttributeValue, classObj.Name);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation / inline code comments to explain how your code works and will solve OP's query.

Answer (score 0):

If instead

> [DisplayName("Something To Name")]

you use

> [Display(Name = "Something To Name")]

Just do this:

```
private string GetDisplayName(Class1 class1)
{
    string displayName = string.Empty;

    string propertyName = class1.Name.GetType().Name;

    CustomAttributeData displayAttribute = class1.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AttributeType.Name == "DisplayAttribute");

    if (displayAttribute != null)
    {
        displayName = displayAttribute.NamedArguments.FirstOrDefault().TypedValue.Value;
    }

    return displayName;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This code worked for me...

Class definition:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Class1{
     [Display(Name = "Something To Name")]
     public string PropertyOfMyClass1{ get; set; } 
 }
```

in your own method:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

string displayName = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(x => x.PropertyOfMyClass1, new ViewDataDictionary<Class1>()).DisplayName;
```

Result:

> displayName --> "Something To Name"

in your code change `PropertyOfMyClass1` and `Class1` with your own values.

Comment: Your answer doesn't provide more information than the existing answers (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015872/10352740)), I think you should read the [help center for answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), especially [How to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Reasons leading to answer deletion](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)