# Binding read data annotation

Tags: wpf, data-annotations

I have this C# object ( Current, Monitor.CarNumber value is 123456 )

```
    public class Monitor
    {
        [Display(Name = "This is car number")]
        public string CardNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

And in WPF, An Label control display Monitor.CardNumber

```
<Label Content={Binding CardNumber} />
```

( When I run the program. it display 123567, It work correctly ).

Now I don't want it display the CardNumber's value, I want it display the "This is car number" ( the Data Annotation of CardNumber Property ).

How should I do that ? ( No C# code, only modify above XML code )

Comment: WPF has no built-in support for the `Display` attribute, and there is no XAML syntax for reading attributes. So unfortunately your requirement of "no C# code" can't be met.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a combination of `Converter` and `Reflection` to get the Display Name in binding.

When you bind your label with `CardNumber`, the Converter will look for the attached attribute using Reflection and if it find `DisplayAttribute`, will return the Name property from attribute for Binding, else return the CardNumber.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10048758/823369) answer on SO will help you to get the Display.Name using Reflection.

This doesn't looks as simple as I have answered, since you have to Pass the Property Name to the converter.