# ASP.NET MVC - Display name for the whole model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I know there's a `DisplayName` and `Display` for model properties like so :

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Licence")]
    public string Licence { get; set; }
}
```

But is there a `Display` for the **whole** model ? May be something like this :

```
[Display(Name = "My beautiful model")]
public class MyModel
{
...
```

And if so, how to access it from HTML ?

Comment: How do you want to use such attribute?

Comment: Are you trying to control JSON serialization? If so, can you include some of your code.

Comment: I have a CRUD table, and I want the title to be read from the model, not hard-coded in the HTML

Comment: @timothyclifford No I'm not

Comment: what do you mean by "whole model" ?

Comment: Just use the viewbag,.  ie.  ViewBage.PageTitle = "Whatever..."  and in the view  @ViewBag.PageTitle    ,  the value frome page title is set when you get your model data in the controller.

Comment: You could use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5015911/3999513

Comment: I would be happy if whoever understood what is "whole model" could share this with me.

Comment: @Veverke Like a title for the model

Comment: @Mehdiway:  what do you mean by "a title for the model" ? Can it be thought as an ordinary property in the model ? If so, why do not you add it ? And if you add, then what will be the problem ?

Comment: I could do what @Canvas did in his answer but that's not the *official* way to do it, just a workaround

Answer (score 6):

You could add another property to your model called Title and then in the get set that like so

```
public string PageTitle
{
    get
    {
        return "Attribut de licence";
    }
}
```

This could work. This is quite crude, but I don't think you can add a display attribute to a model itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to override ToString method ?

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(Name)
      .Append(" ")
      .Append(Surname);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```