# How to get the Value in [Display(Name="")] attribute in Controller for any property using EF6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an MVC 5 application. I want to get the value in  **[Display(Name = "")]** attribute in my controller method for any property of any class.

My model is as:

```
public partial class ABC
{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "Transaction No")]
   public string S1 { get; set; }
}
```

I have looked [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute), but it is a little lengthy procedure. I am looking for something readily available and built-in.

So, I have tried this:

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(ABC).GetProperty(s); // s is a string type which has the property name ... in this case it is S1
var dd = property.CustomAttributes.Select(x => x.NamedArguments.Select(y => y.TypedValue.Value)).OfType<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute>();
```

But I have 2 problems, First I am not getting the value i.e. "Transaction No". And secondly even though I have mentioned **.OfType<>** I am still getting all attributes i.e. [Display(Name="")] and [Required].

But luckily I am getting the "Transaction No" value in

> property>>CustomAttribute>>[1]>>NamedArguments>>[0]>>TypedValue>>Value
>   = "Transaction No"

Since **TypedValue.Value** has the required value, So how can I retrieve it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(ABC).GetProperty(s); 
var dd = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
if(dd != null)
{
  var name = dd.Name;
}
```

Comment: THANKS.. It worked for me.. **typeof(ABC)**// or the model for which property is required

Comment: I tried it but the value is not passed to property. I tried replacing s with my model's value. But when i hover at memberinfo property.... the property is null. why is this? I don't know if it is because my model value is enum? how can i fix it? this is my line: typeof(MyProject.Dom.Title).GetProperty(Card.Title.ToString())

Comment: @Nurul, Comment is not a place to ask questions like "here is my code, why it doesn't work". please post it as a separate question, and include your code.

Comment: Why does this take so much code? Seems like a simple thing to do

Answer (score 5):

You can use it:

```
MemberInfo property = typeof(ABC).GetProperty(s); 
var name = property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is [Ahmed Galal's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55312665/5405967) formulated as a static method in a utility class, for convenience:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Project
{
    public static class AttributeGetter
    {
        public static string DisplayName<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            MemberInfo property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
            return property.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()?.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
string displayName = AttributeGetter.DisplayName<VM>(nameof(VM.Prop));
```

Answer (score 2):

Alex Art's answer almost worked for me.  `dd.Name` simply returned the property name, but `dd.GetName()` returned the text from the `Display` attribute.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee Just tried that an it also returns the property name, not the text from the `Display` attribute.