# How do I access DisplayAtribute from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.PropertyEntry

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

In the Database context, when accessing properties before calling SaveChanges, how do I get the Displayname rather than simply the name (the below code)?

```
string changes = "";
foreach (var item in ctx.Entry(entity).Properties)
{
    if (item.IsModified)
    {
        changes += "["+item.Metadata.Name+"]";
    }
}
```

Comment: display name of the property? you mean name mentioned in `Display` attribute? like `[Display(Name="some name")]` ?

Comment: maybe this can help 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5015878/6027876

Comment: Thanks, that got me a little further. When I do this:

    var attribute = item.Metadata.PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true);

the debugger tells me I have {System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute[0]}

and attribute.GetType() gives me (shortened):

{System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute[]}
    AssemblyQualifiedName: "System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute[],     Name: "DisplayNameAttribute[]"
{System.ComponentModel.DisplayNameAttribute[]}

But

attribute.Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();

gives 
null

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32808219/6027876

Comment: Thanks, that got me close enough; in my case, this works:

    var fieldName = item.Metadata.Name;    
MemberInfo property = typeof(ApplicationForm).GetProperty(item.Metadata.Name);
    var ca = property.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) as DisplayAttribute;
    if (ca != null)
    {
        fieldName = ca.Name;
    }

Comment: you're welcome, glad to help.