# How do I get a space in my property name?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I have the following query:

```
var query = _projectEmployeesBLL.GetAll()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeID == employee.EmployeeID 
           && x.project.isActive == true 
           && x.project.isDelected == false)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        x.project.ProjectID,
        ProjeAdı = x.project.Name,
    });
```

The problem is that I make the property `ProjeAdı` in the Select clause. I want the property to match the sql column, `Proje Adı` (note the space). How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try `Proje_Adi`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aliases cant have spaces between them , just like any variable name cant have white space, they are considered as bad naming conventions, you can use _(underscore) eg. Proje_Adi

Answer (score 4):

while this might not be useful in your case, someone else looking for a way can use the 'DisplayName' attribute that can come in handy when enumerating properties as propertiesDescriptor.
I had a similar requirement.
here's how to use it-

```
[DisplayName("Father Name")]
public string FatherName{get;set;}
```

then access it using

```
propertyDescriptor.DisplayName
```

or byways shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute)