# Get the all the values of DisplayName attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, data-annotations

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 with EntityFramework 6 DataAnnotations.
I would like to know if there is a way to get all `DisplayName` of an object and save them in a variable into a Controller class.

For example, considering the class:

```
public class Class1
{
    [DisplayName("The ID number")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("My Value")]
    public int Value { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Label name to display")]
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

How to get the values of `DisplayName` for all attributes? For example how to create a function that returns a `Dictionary< string,string >` which has a key with attribute name and value with `DisplayName`, like this:

```
{ "Id": "The ID name", "Value": "My Value", "Label": "Label name to display"}.
```

I have seen this topic [stackoverflow - get the value of DisplayName attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute) but I have no ideas of a way to extends this code.

Comment: `DisplayName` or `Display` (they are different)?

Comment: @IvanStoev `DisplayName`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't really care for the `DisplayName` attribute, but the effective display name that will be used (for instance by data binding), the easiest is to use [`TypeDescriptor.GetProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybh0y4fd(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var info = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Class1))
    .Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.DisplayName);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have encapsulated your code for working with Generic Class and it continue to works. You solve my problem!

Comment: Would it be possible to get a dictionary with the values of the display names and a reference to the function itself? Even if this is only possible for static methods.

Comment: @Reiner Not sure I follow, can you give an example?

Comment: Lets assume that that the `[DisplayName("The ID number")]
    public static int Id { get; set; }` method would be added into a dictionary
`Dictionary<string, Func>` as entry object:
`{"The ID number", Class1.Id}` and could be used with 
`int id = dic["The ID number"]`

Comment: @Reiner So you want a dictionary with display name being a key, and value being... hmm, not sure what. Most likely what you need is possible, but consider posting your own question with the specific requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below -

```
 Class1 c = new Class1();
 PropertyInfo[] listPI = c.GetType().GetProperties();
 Dictionary<string, string> dictDisplayNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();
 string displayName = string.Empty;

 foreach (PropertyInfo pi in listPI)
 {
    DisplayNameAttribute dp = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().SingleOrDefault();
            if (dp != null)
            {
                displayName = dp.DisplayName;
                dictDisplayNames.Add(pi.Name, displayName);
            }
 }
```

I have also referred to same link that you have mentioned in the question.

the final dictionary is as -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer but unfortunately your code doesn't work on my project.

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: It returns "Sequence contains no elements" in the displayName assignment into the foreach loop.

Comment: Oh! sorry @Cyr there was a typo

Comment: Oh! sorry @Cyr there was a typo, I have edited in the answer. It was inside the foreach loop - 
displayName = pi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single().DisplayName;

Comment: Now it works. But if an attribute in the Model don't have the `[DisplayName("field name")]` DataAnnotation, it returns a  System.InvalidOperationException (due to empty sequence).

Comment: Then you have to add code to check if the attribute is null. I have edited the answer accordingly.