# With EntityFramework, how to access DisplayName for foreign key columns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following annotations :

```
    [Display(Name = "NotImportant", ResourceType = typeof(MyResxFile))]
    public int? PhoneModel { get; set; } // this is the id
    [Display(Name = "Important", ResourceType = typeof(MyResxFile))]
    public virtual PhoneModel PhoneModel1 { get; set; } // this is the object
```

I use the following method to get the display name :

```
    PropertyInfo pi = SomeObject.GetProperties[0]; // short example
    columnName = ReflectionExtensions.GetDisplayName(pi);
```

It works for all columns **except** the code finds no custom/display attribute for columns such as PhoneModel1 even if there is clearly one attribute. It works for the **int?** but I don't need the header for the **id**, I need the header for the actual value, which is in PhoneModel1.

```
    public static class ReflectionExtensions
    {

        public static T GetAttribute<T>(this MemberInfo member, bool isRequired)
            where T : Attribute
        {
            var attribute = member.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(T), false).SingleOrDefault();

            if (attribute == null && isRequired)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    string.Format(
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        "The {0} attribute must be defined on member {1}",
                        typeof(T).Name,
                        member.Name));
            }

            return (T)attribute;
        }

        public static string GetDisplayName(PropertyInfo memberInfo)
        {
            var displayAttribute = memberInfo.GetAttribute<DisplayAttribute>(false);

            if (displayAttribute != null)
            {
                ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager(displayAttribute.ResourceType);
                var entry = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, true, true)
                                           .OfType<DictionaryEntry>()
                                           .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Key.ToString() == displayAttribute.Name);

                return entry.Value.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                var displayNameAttribute = memberInfo.GetAttribute<DisplayNameAttribute>(false);
                if (displayNameAttribute != null)
                {
                    return displayNameAttribute.DisplayName;
                }
                else
                {
                    return memberInfo.Name;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `GetDisplayName` extension method should look like this:

```
public static string GetDisplayName(this PropertyInfo pi)
{
    if (pi == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pi));
    }
    return pi.IsDefined(typeof(DisplayAttribute)) ? pi.GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>().GetName() : pi.Name;
}
```

And to use it:

```
PropertyInfo pi = SomeObject.GetProperties[0];
string columnName = pi.GetDisplayName();
```

Note that if the property doesn't define a `DisplayName` attribute we return the property name.

Comment: thanks a lot, you made my day ! the magic was to use GetName() instead of .Name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var attribute =typeof(MyClass).GetProperty("Name").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), true).Cast<DisplayNameAttribute>().Single();
string displayName = attribute.DisplayName;
```

Hopefully It's help for you.