# ASP .Net MVC 5 Get Attributes of properties of model in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I manage to make my problem on dropdownlist work but still i encountered another issue. this is my new code;

```
@foreach (var props in mymodel.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            <div class="editor-line">
                <label>@props.Name </label>
                @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                    .Name("ddl1_" + @props.Name)
                    .OptionLabel("Select")
                    .DataTextField("Text")
                    .DataValueField("Value")
                    .AutoBind(false)                    
                    .Events(e => e.Change("onSelect"))
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 25%" })
                )
            </div>
        }
```

and here's how i populate them, sorry for the bad practice.

```
@foreach (var props in mymodel.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
            {
                <text>
                    var ddl = $('#ddl1_' + "@props.Name").data("kendoDropDownList");
                    ddl.setDataSource(ddlSource);
                </text>
            }
```

now my problem is the `.Events(e => e.Change("onSelect"))` code is not working, it makes may page fail to load because it cannot find the `onSelect` function.

here is the code in javsacript

```
function onSelect(e) {
        debugger;
        if (e.item) {
            var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
            var elementId = e.sender.element[0].id
            console.log(elementId);
            console.log("event :: select (" + dataItem.Text + " : " + dataItem.Value + ")");
        } else {
            console.log("event :: select");
        }
    }
```

Comment: See if this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute

Comment: So whats preventing you to do so in your controller?

Comment: I did this on the Controller side.
List<PropertyInfo> result =
                        GetEntityModel(4)
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Where(
                            p =>
                                p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CanBulkUpdateAttribute), true)
                                .Where(ca => ((CanBulkUpdateAttribute)ca).CanBulkUpdate)
                                .Any()
                            )
                        .ToList();

Comment: But the purpose of this is after all the process on the view is passed to the controller. Meaning I am already expecting the model <to get the only properties needed>, the property name and the value of dropdownlist <to know what value is to be passed and to that property and save to database>. how can i use that in the view side to output only what i need?