# Using Html.DisplayFor() and Html.DisplayNameFor() outside of ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core

I have three projects under one solution: website (razor pages), model and a class library for creating static HTML documents. For now I only really need the model and the library to be used inside the website, but I separated them in case I need to reuse them later.

I would like to use [`Html.DisplayNameFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper-1.displaynamefor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [`Html.DisplayFor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper-1.displayfor?view=aspnetcore-5.0) inside the class library, since I have already given `Display` and `DataType` attributes to the model. The problem is that those methods are inside `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` namespace.

I tried finding the NuGet package, but only found that Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures is in 2.2.0 version and it also installs .Http, .Authorization, and other stuff that I don't really need.
I found [get the value of DisplayName attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015830/get-the-value-of-displayname-attribute), but it only works for the name and I believe it would be cumbersome to write something similar for every `DataType` as well.

How can I get those two methods inside library? Or could I just merge the library into the website project that has already everything?

Comment: After you build your whole solution all the required libs would be side to the application and I think if you reference what you need, it would not be a problem.

Comment: The accepted answer to the linked question includes the generic `GetAttribute<T>` function, which lets you get any attribute of any type. You can see how it is used in the `GetPropertyDisplayName` function. It should be easy to copy/paste that `GetPropertyDisplayName` function and replace `DisplayName` with `Display` to create a `GetPropertyDisplay` function. Even better if you step through the code and attempt to understand what the code is doing...

Comment: Well problem really rises when I need to implement ```DisplayFor()```. It uses ```DataType``` attribute to change the string output. For example it returns only a date string from ```DateTime``` with attribute ```[DataType(DataType.Date)]``` .